# How to put padding between breadcrumb elements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

I'm using a rails gem that generates breadcrumbs in the following format:

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <a href="/">Home</a> &raquo;
  <a href="/category/computers">Computers</a> &raquo;
  Walmart
</div>
```

Is there a way in CSS that I can reference the `&raquo;` and apply padding and color changes to it?

Comment: Which gem are you using?

Comment: Breadcrumb On Rails -- https://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails/

Comment: Oyi veh... They just updated the gem to allow an options hash to specify the separator. Now I could pass a span tag to the separator and solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. However, seeing that you're using breadcrumbs on rails, just use this to display them:

```
render_breadcrumbs :separator => '<span class="sep">&raquo;</span>'
```

and then style away on the `span.sep`.

Comment: Thanks! :) I just saw that on their github page -- my outdated gem didn't have that option (which they recently pushed).

Answer (score 1):

No, but you always use the `<a>` tags for this.

```
.breadcrumbs a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 5px;
    color:green;
}
.breadcrumbs {
    color:navyblue;
}
```

Comment: This won't handle the "and color changes" part of the question.

Comment: Yeah that's what I did at first too -- only problem is the last element which is not in the <a> tag :)

Comment: Oh Right!! Although you can color the `&raquo`'s and last item altogether, but not separately. http://jsfiddle.net/sGe6y/

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can cheat:

```
.breadcrumbs {
    color: #f00; /* whatever color you want your &raquo;s to be */
}

.breadcrumbs a {
    color: #007 !important; /* override the color of the link back to default */
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

/* also override these to make sure they don't get colored wrong */
.breadcrumbs a:hover { color: #009 !important; }
.breadcrumbs a:active { color: #009 !important; }
```

This should have the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer no, however you could so something like....

```
<a href="/">home</a><span>&raquo;</span>
```

then do a style on the span however a better method for this would be to use `<ul><li>` tags.

Is there a reason why the » is not in the A tag~?